# Transform a specific row of a dataframe into a vector

Tags: r

How to transform a specific row of a dataframe into a vector.

In this case, I would like to transform `df1[3,2:3]` into a vector.

Thank you so much!

```
df1<- structure(
  list(
   Name = c("Name1","Name2", "Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6"),
    Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.930473,-24.95575,-24.95575,-24.950473,-24.950473), 
    Longitude = c(-49.994889,-49.994889, -49.990162,-49.990162,-49.996889,-49.996889)),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df1[3,2:3]

> df1[3,2:3]
   Latitude Longitude
3 -24.95575 -49.99016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unlist`

```r
df1<- structure(
  list(
    Name = c("Name1","Name2", "Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6"),
    Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.930473,-24.95575,-24.95575,-24.950473,-24.950473), 
    Longitude = c(-49.994889,-49.994889, -49.990162,-49.990162,-49.996889,-49.996889)),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

vec <- unlist(df1[3,2:3])
vec
#>  Latitude Longitude 
#> -24.95575 -49.99016
class(vec)
#> [1] "numeric"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>